# Table view Loaded automatically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am using 8 cells in a `UITableView`. Each cell has a group of components like `UIButton`, `UILabel` and `UISlider`. When I update the 6th cell, it reflects to 1st `cell`. Similarly, if I update the 7th cell, it reflects to 2nd cell.

How can I prevent this?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {    
   return 1;
 }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return viewcount;
 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
   NSString *MyIdentifier=@"mycell";


   ListCell1 *cell = (ListCell1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil)
  {
    cell = [[ListCell1 alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier]; 
  }

  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
  UIButton *b=[buttonarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
  b.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
  cell.imageView.image=b.imageView.image;
  return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   ListCell1 *cell1 = (ListCell1 *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   [cell1 addSubview:delbutton];
   delpath=indexPath;
 }

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return 100.0;
 }
```

Comment: can you include the code you are using?, if not it is really difficult for us to help you

Comment: Paste your code please... Blind hint, read about UITableView cell reuse

Comment: @Krishnan can you post your table view code and elaborate more your question.

Comment: post code of cellForRowAtIndexpath method

Comment: Is the image of the 6th cell the same as the 1st as well? It shouldn't be given your code.

Comment: No.i am not adding image in cell, My cell containing label,button and slider.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method with

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       // cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }
    **// and add UIButton, UILabel and UISlider. in cell.contentView**

}
```

May be it is helpful for you :)

**EDIT**

In Your Case, You need to Change only `NSString *CellIdentifier` and  **put this from in my Answer**
And  create custom method for **initialize** all the component that are put on cell, in this method only do initialization of all components and afte initialization complite **call this method before cell is created** and after call this method, you need to add this component to your `UITableVieCell` (`cell.ContentView`) ;) **Try it :)**

Comment: I am creating cell in another class. Listcell.h and Listcell.m

Comment: If i delete one cell.It reset all the data in other cell

Comment: I am new to here please tell me how to get in for chat

Comment: i dono to send.-(void)deletecell:(id)sender

     what should be i my delete method?

Comment: put code or best way to send your project to my email .. :) your choice :) you can also give up vote :)

Comment: I am adding my code in new question please check it and give me a solution

Comment: Check my new question now and helpme.

Comment: iPatel check my new question and tell me.

Answer (score 0):

try to set

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d:%d", indexPath.row, indexPath.section];
```

Comment: I used your code but my cell values become reset.How to avoid this problem

Comment: Now i am getting this problem after changing the code.If i delete one cell.It reset all the data in other cell

Comment: so maybe we can understand better your problem if post the code of the delete table cel

Answer (score 0):

Try This for `CellForRowAtIndexPath`

Code::

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"name";
    customCell *cell = (customCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib;
        nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"name" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id oneObject in nib)
            if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[customCell class]])
                cell = (customCell *)oneObject;

        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

        cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        b.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
        cell.imageView.image=b.imageView.image;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Hopefully, It'll work. Thanks.

Comment: Now i am getting this problem after changing the code. If i delete one cell.It reset all the data in other cell

Comment: set Tag value to cell. May be it'll solve it. Because when you're scrolling tableview, it'll reload all data automatically and call all 4 methods of it.